# Bundle deployment only for selected gems

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I would like to run `bundle --deployment` only for one group of gems that are not provided by the system. I've tried using `--with=group` but it started doing for all gems in the `Gemfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler's `--with` option works a bit different than what you're expecting. Let's first look at the [`bundle install`](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/bundle-install.1.html) man page for `--without` and `--with` options:

> `--without=<list>`
>
> A space-separated list of groups referencing gems to
>   skip during installation. If a group is given that is in the
>   remembered list of groups given to --with, it is removed from that
>   list. This is a [remembered option](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/bundle-install.1.html#REMEMBERED-OPTIONS).
>
> `--with=<list>`
>
> A space-separated list of groups referencing gems to install. If an optional group is given it is installed. If a group is
>   given that is in the remembered list of groups given to --without, it
>   is removed from that list. This is a [remembered option](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/bundle-install.1.html#REMEMBERED-OPTIONS).

It is important to note that `--with` is *not* just the inverse of `--without` (although a `--with` group *does* cancel out a previously-remembered `--without` group and vice versa), it supports an entirely different feature (one [implemented](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/3531) more recently, around mid-2015), the (backwards-compatible) concept of an "optional group", which only applies to groups explicitly marked with the `optional => true` parameter.

Importantly, the `--with` implementation does *not* exclude gems from either the default group or any other group not specified by `--without`.

So you have two options for restricting your installation to just a single group of gems:

1. Whitelist using `--with` by marking all groups as "optional groups" (using `:optional => true` parameter) and passing the group(s) you wish to install to `--with`, leaving all other optional groups excluded.
2. Blacklist using `--without` by passing all groups you do not wish to install to `--without`.

Unfortunately, neither option is able to prevent gems in the "default group" (gems not assigned to a group explicitly) from being installed, so you must place all gems you ever want to potentially exclude in some group.

The following Gemfile example should help clarify:

```
gem "rack" # Always installed; impossible to exclude

group :group, :optional => true do
  gem "thin" # Not installed by default; install using --with=group
end
group :another_group, :optional => true do
  gem "wirble" # Not installed by default; install using --with=another_group
end
group :third_group do
  gem "activesupport", "2.3.5" # Installed by default; exclude using --without=third_group
end
```

Comment: thank you, I tested and it works! As a sidenote for multiple `with` or `without` options must be done using `:` as separator, like this: `bundle --path vendor/bundle --without runtime:cucumber:vendor:production:development`

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993642/bundle-install-selected-group-into-custom-path