# Bundle install selected group into custom path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

As a follow up to [Bundle deployment only for selected gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060410/bundle-deployment-only-for-selected-gems), using the solution of blacklisting using `--without` option, for example:

```
group :runtime do
  gem 'rails'
  ...
end
group :runtime_unpackaged do
  gem 'less2sass'
end
```

The `runtime_unpackaged` can be installed using the command:

```
bundle --path vendor/bundle --without runtime
```

The `runtime` group is installed through debian packages as the application itself is packaged as a .deb package.

But then all other gems at group `runtime` won't be handled anymore by the application as this command will create a file `.bundle/config` that filters them out.

In other words, I want to load the application using gems from the system - debian jessie packages - (group `runtime`) and also gems installed locally at `vendor/bundle` (group `runtime_unpackaged`).

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly? What exactly in the actual terminal output from running `bundle --path vendor/bundle --without runtime` is not behaving how you expect/want?

Comment: @wjordan after that command the application won't run as it won't load all the gems needed, that's is basically the issue. part of the gems comes from the system (debian packages) and the other are bundled at `vendor/bundle`

Comment: "the application won't run as it won't load all the gems needed" is still too ambiguous. Please copy and paste the exact output of the terminal command(s) with error codes, and the full source code of all related files in a minimally-reproducible example. Otherwise, it's too unclear what exactly you're attempting to do and what exactly is the error, and no one else will be able to reproduce your issue closely enough to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Bundler and have it load both groups, you should just be able to run `bundle install` and leave out the `--without` flag.  You can also set specific groups to get run with `bundle install` in your application.rb file using Bundler.require(:group1, :group2, etc..).  Check out [Bundler.io's](http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html) section on groups

Comment: I want only one group to be installed with bundle install as the other group was installed through debian packages